# Minecraft keeps shutting down with exit code 0

Tags: nixos, minecraft

I'm trying to run Minecraft on NixOS with Sway, and the launcher works fine but every time I want to launch the game it shuts down and the launcher displays an error message with exit code 0.

I've got jdk11, jk8 and jre8 installed.

Comment: Run it in console, check any error messages.

Comment: This is the only error message I get when launching the launcher : `[0122/180441.276350:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(346)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.`

Comment: Looks like https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-9795 Please try using classic JRE: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html if I were you I'd uninstall all existing Java compilers first.

Comment: Is it not available on the official Nix repository ?

Comment: JRE from Oracle is proprietary and I've no clue whether it's available for any particular one of 10,000,000,000 distros out there. I wonder why you cannot just download an RPM, DEB or tar.gz and install it.

Comment: I've tried with jre8 but the same error appears.

Comment: If you're sure you're using the right java executable, please use their bug tracker. Probably a specific JRE is required but I've no idea which.